# Query not show after 16th data input

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble with my formula that includes query inside.
My formula works fine from first data until 15th data, but after I input 16th data, it's not working anymore, do query have any limitation?
Or something wrong with my formula?

Here a screen capture  for working condition
[image]

And here a screen capture after I input new data
[image]

**Link Sheet:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jsTcjt-s4tSYKkJDlDLLt5rnBDYTxmaOnZIJOjBXoy4/edit?usp=sharing

NB: my formula work with validation on Sheet Data Column V, it will match with current date, so in screen capture the current date is 08/07/2019 (dd/mm/yyyy), so I input 08/07/2019, and then that row of data will go to "Print Content" Sheet, and from there the data will move to "Print" Sheet

Comment: What is the formula you are talking about?

Comment: sorry, im forgot to add the sheet link

Comment: this the formula im using for call Item Name =iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, query('Print Content'!$A:$F,"select F where A='" & A73 & "' limit 50",0))),"")&Char(10)

Comment: Your explanation of how your spreadsheet works, the role of the various sheets and the problem that you are experiencing are unclear. Would you please re-read this important help topic [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then edit your question to demonstrate and explain how your spreadsheet works, the formula that you are using, and reproduce the exact problem that you are having.